# Two way binding on Array elements using <form>

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, angular-template

I have an array of objects in a component. which I will iterate in the template.

#### app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'sample-app';
  classesData = [];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.classesData = [
      {title: 'Hello0'}, {title: 'Hello1'}, {title: 'Hello2'}
    ];
  }

  duplicate() {
    const newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.classesData[1]));
    newData.title += 'Copy';
    this.classesData.splice(1, 0, newData);
  }
}
```

#### app.template.html

```
<form #testingFrom="ngForm">
  <p>{{classesData | json}}</p>
  <div *ngFor="let classData of classesData; let i=index">
    <input [(ngModel)]="classData.title" name="{{'title-' + i}}" type="text">
  </div>
  <button (click)="duplicate()">Duplicate</button>
</form>
```

My aim is when a user clicks on the **duplicate** button I simply add a new element at **index 1** in an array. My initial state looks like (before user clicks)

[image]

And my state after a user clicks duplicate button

[image]

In the image above at 3rd input field, we are getting **Hello1Copy** instead of **Hello1**.

Comment: Either I'm missing the point, or you are not specifying your issue.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Why `this.classesData[1]`? I mean, why are you taking index 1? What is the duplicate button meant to duplicate? the first item? the last item? all items?

Comment: @SakutoI have added an issue details

Comment: @briosheje this is just a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely suspect that this behavior is happening because of conflict in the `name` attribute value. For this case only, if you `splice` the `newItem` at first location, it only adds that's variable and other DOM's doesn't re-render. For cross verification you can try replacing `input` element with simple binding like `{{classData.title}}` and everything works fine.

This behavior can easily be solved by not conflicting `name` attribute value for all time. What that means is to assign a unique `id` variable with each collection item and use it.

```
this.classesData = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Hello0' }, 
  { id: 2, title: 'Hello1' }, 
  { id: 3, title: 'Hello2' }
];
duplicate() {
    const newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.classesData[1]));
    newData.title += 'Copy';
    newData.id = Date.now()
    this.classesData.splice(1, 0, newData);
}
```

**Template**

```
<div *ngFor="let classData of classesData;let i=index">
   <input [(ngModel)]="classData.title" [name]="'title_'+classData.id" type="text">
</div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzzufe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

---

You can also verify the same by removing `name` attribute from each input field. But that would not suffice, it would throw

> ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name
>   attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as
>   'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

So add `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` on each input field to make input working without `name` attribute. As suggested in another answer by @briosheje, you can also re-enforce rendering using `trackBy`.

PS: I'm investigating why this works differently when there is a combination of `name` and `input`, I suspect about `form` API wiring with `input` element. I'll update the answer as soon as I get something.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a form. Because you're using a form, you need to specify how angular should track the changes for your form items, if you're planning to **alter** the existing source. You can do such using the `trackBy` pipe:

```
<form #testingFrom="ngForm">
  <p>{{classesData | json}}</p>
  <div *ngFor="let classData of classesData; let i=index; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <input [(ngModel)]="classData.title" [name]="'title-' + i" type="text">
  </div>
  <button (click)="duplicate()">Duplicate</button>
</form>
```

Typescript relevant part:

```
  trackByFn(index: any) {
    return index;
  }
```

Please note that **adding** elements to the collection will work in your original example.

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uabuya

Answer (score 0):

Make another variable and iterate that variable to crate inputs

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'sample-app';
  originalData=[];
  classesData = [];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.classesData = [
      {title: 'Hello0'}, {title: 'Hello1'}, {title: 'Hello2'}
    ];
    this.originalData=[...this.classesData]; // changed here
  }

  duplicate() {
    const newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.classesData[1]));
    newData.title += 'Copy';
    this.classesData.splice(1, 0, newData);
  }
}
```

[Working Demo](https://angular-cm3de6.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your issue using "trackBy" feature. Please see below code sample.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'sample-app';
  classesData = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.classesData = [
      { title: 'Hello0' },
      { title: 'Hello1' },
      { title: 'Hello2' }
    ];
  }

  duplicate() {
    const newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.classesData[1]));
    newData.title += 'Copy';
    this.classesData.splice(1, 0, newData);
  }

  trackByIndex(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<form>
  <p>{{classesData | json}}</p>
  <div *ngFor="let classData of classesData; let i=index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
    <input [(ngModel)]="classesData[i].title" name="{{'title-' + i}}" type="text" />
  </div>
  <button (click)="duplicate()">Duplicate</button>
</form>
```

Please let me know if this solution works for you!